# What actually happen behind Path.Combine

Tags: c#, asp.net, path

I have :

```
string Combine = Path.Combine("shree\\", "file1.txt");
string Combine1 = Path.Combine("shree", "file1.txt");
```

Both gives same result :

`shree\file1.txt`

What actually happen behind  `Path.Combine`?Which is the best coding practice to do this.please clear my vision.Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the first path (shree or shree\\) does not end with a valid separator character (e.g. [DirectorySeparatorChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar.aspx)) it is appended to the path before concatenation.

So

```
string path1 = "shree";
string path2 = "file1.txt";
string combined = Path.Combine(path1, path2);
```

will result in "shree\file1.txt", while

```
string path1 = "shree\\";
```

already contains a valid separator character, so the Combine method will not add another one.

Here you typed two slashes in the string variable (path1). The first one just acts as an escape character for the second one. This is the same as using a verbatim string literal.

```
string path1 = @"shree\";
```

More information on the Combine method can be found on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the second one. This way you don't care about what is the directory separator.

Answer (score 0):

> What actually happen behind Path.Combine?

It builds you a path... so it's doesn't matter what of those two you will use. but those `\\` are redundant.
If you're interested with micro optimization, create a test which of the two is faster.